# How to configure the RequiresDuplicateDetection for AzureServiceBus topics

Tags: c#, masstransit

I am trying to configure the `RequiresDuplicateDetection` property on the ASB topics to true, but it doesn't appear that the setting on the main `IServiceBusFactoryConfigurator` is respected:

```
        var busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.Host("ASB_ConnectionString");
            cfg.SubscriptionEndpoint<ExtractionRequest>("Test", e =>
            {
                e.LockDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
                e.MaxAutoRenewDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
                e.AutoDeleteOnIdle = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
            });
            cfg.RequiresDuplicateDetection = true;
        });
```

Any topics that are created for this subscription on ASB don't seem to respect the setting. I found a (maybe hacky) way to actually work around by hooking into the `TopicDescription` object on the `PublishTopology` of my message type.

```
        var smth = busControl.Topology.Publish<ExtractionRequest>() as ServiceBusMessagePublishTopology<ExtractionRequest>;
        smth.TopicDescription.RequiresDuplicateDetection = true;
```

The topics that are created correctly after this workaround. If anyone can shed some light on this, that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure the publish topology for the topic within the bus configurator:

```
cfg.Publish<ExtractionRequest>(x => x.RequiresDuplicateDetection = true);
```

> You should configure the topology prior to configuring your subscription endpoint, order matters particularly in this case.

In your example, specifying `cfg.RequiresDuplicateDetection = true;` configures the bus receive endpoint only, not the subscription endpoint or any other configured receive endpoints.

Comment: Thank you very much, and it does actually matter that you configure the topology prior to configuring the subscription endpoint (just checked).